# FireFox capture autocomplete input change event

Tags: javascript, firefox, autocomplete

I'm trying to subscribe to change events on an input tag for an ajax auto complete form. These change events are not firing when the user clicks an autocomplete suggestion from FireFox.

I've seen fixes for IE, but not FireFox. You can view this behavior [here](http://jehiah.cz/sandbox/onchange.html)

Steps to recreate:
type any input in one of the boxes and click submit.

Start typing the value again in the same box.

You should see the autocomplete suggestion box appear below the input box. Notice that clicking the suggestion does not fire the change event (it also doesn't fire the click event)

Currently my only option is to disable autocomplete on this field, but I do not want to do that.

Comment: Please, switch the "right answer" mark to Jethro's answer. The hack in the answer you marked as the right answer is not necessary!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it makes you feel better, it is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87943)

Proposed workaround: (Not mine, from [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=584166&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Mozilla Firefox Problem</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fOnChange()
{
  alert('OnChange Fired');
}

var val_textBox;

function fOnFocus()
{
  val_textBox = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
}

function fOnBlur()
{
  if (val_textBox != document.getElementById('textBox').value) {
    fOnChange();
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="textBox" name="textBox" onFocus="fOnFocus()" onBlur="fOnBlur()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposed workaround Serapth, but it'd be pretty difficult to apply on a 50 fields form page, don't you think ?

Answer (score 32):

Firefox 4+ fire 'oninput' event when autocomplete is used.
Here's some jQuery to make this more actionable:

```
$('#password').bind('input', function(){ /* your code */});
```

Comment: Be aware: This was not supported until IE9 and Safari 5. Safari 4 supported `textinput`.

Comment: The question specifically was asking about FF and this works there at least as far back as FF3.5 if I remember right.

Comment: Indeed, oninput is fired too in Google Chrome (26+ at least). With Mootools capturing "input" event works perfect!

Comment: +1 : This answer should be marked as the correct one! Here is the [Mozilla documentation about input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input).

Comment: 'input' event not fired for `password` field when autocomplete was for `login` field, and in similar situations

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same problem.

Apparently, there is password manager debugging available
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox:Password_Manager_Debugging

So I've found that for me **DOMAutoComplete** event got triggered and
I've managed to attach it sucessfuly to a field via jQuery's bind like

```
$('#email').bind('DOMAutoComplete',function() { ...
```

Comment: This must be very browser specific... It would be great to see more info on this... I tried this in Chrome and it did not work

Comment: Works great in FF30! Might be specific but better than nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another Suggested work around. This time using polling, you can work it in exactly
the same way, checking for "changes" to your field. Tweak the poll value (default to
375ms for your own taste).

I've used jQuery and a jquery plugin someone wrote:
https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-dotimeout/

Git Hub Src: https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-dotimeout/master/jquery.ba-dotimeout.js

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>onChange() for Firefox / IE autofil get-around</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/~dsloan/js/ba-dotimeout.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var val;
            var count=0; // used to illustrate the "poll count" 
                         // when focusing on the element and typing 
                         // (vs not focused)

            // set a focus function to poll the input
            $("#myname").focus(function() {

                // start polling
                $.doTimeout('checkname', 375, function() {
                    ++count;

                    // no changes, just exit this poll
                    if($("#myname").val() == val) {
                        return true;

                    // store the value
                    } else {
                        val = $("#myname").val();
                    }
                    var str;

                    // do stuff here with your field....
                    if($(document.activeElement) && 
                        ($(document.activeElement).attr('id') ==
                        $("#myname").attr('id'))) {

                            var len = $("#myname").val().length;
                            if(len == 0) {
                                str = 'Timer called, length 0...';
                            } else if(len < 2) {
                                str = 'Timer called, length < 2...';
                            } else {
                                str = 'Timer called, valid!';
                            }
                    }

                    // show some debugging...
                    $("#foo span").html(str+' (count: '+count+'): '+
                        $(document.activeElement).attr('id')+
                        ', val: '+$("#myname").val());

                    return true;
                });
            });

            // set a blur function to remove the poll
            $("#myname").blur(function() {
                $.doTimeout('checkname');
            });

        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="#" method=post>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="myname" />
        Scooby: <input name="scooby" value="" id="scooby" />
        <input type="submit" value="Press Me!" />
    </form>
    <div id="foo"><span></span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibly alternative: could you simply use a timer to tell when the value of the text box changes?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to blur the input field and reset the focus to it.  That's going to require a little trickeration though.