# Javascript (jQuery) / HTML: Setting an <input> or <select> to enabled, not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using Mozilla Firefox 14.0.1 and Google Chrome 20.0.1132.57 (latest I think).

My code goes something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SVtDj/

Here's what I want to happen:

1. Enter something on input1
2. Click the disabled input (to trigger the onchange function... see jQuery)

   NOTE: After inputting stuff on input1, we click the disabled input, nothing else.
3. The disabled input should now be enabled. Since by clicking the disabled input, it should trigger the input1's onchange function.

This works in Google Chrome, however, it doesn't work on Mozilla Firefox. How come clicking on the disabled element does not trigger the input's onchange function? This also applies to clicking a disabled  instead of a disabled

Comment: Clicking on disabled input elements in Firefox doesn't change focus, so it won't fire the event. If you press Enter or click on the blank space in the window it still work...

Answer (score 3):

`Disabled` inputs do not trigger `change` and `click` events on FireFox.

```
$('li:eq(1)').click(function(e){
    if($.trim($('#input1').val()).length != 0){
        $('#input2').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SVtDj/10/

instead of `trim()` you can use jQuery `$.trim()`function  which is cross-browser:

```
$('#input1').change(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val()).length != 0){
        $('#input2').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SVtDj/3/)

Comment: This makes no difference in Firefox. Doesn't know why this's ever got upvoted so quickly.

Comment: @Musa yes, it doesn't work because there is no event for disabled inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine.  The issue is that .change() requires a lost of focus (blur) before it triggers.  Try changing it to .keyup()

http://jsfiddle.net/SVtDj/6/

**additional:** this is probably the effect you were going for

```
$('#input1').keyup(function(){
     $('#input2').prop('disabled', $(this).val().trim().length == 0);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend [Ramison's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11626404/887539)

If you want to toggle the disability on `#input2` you can simple:

```
$('#input1').change(function(){
    var isDisabled = !$.trim($(this).val()).length;
    $('#input2').prop('disabled', isDisabled );
});
```

And the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SVtDj/7/

Comment: doesn't works in FF. Clicking the disabled element makes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Firefox needs you type 'enter' or do something else so input1 looses the focus after having wrote in input1 to cast the "onchange" event I think. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865490/firefox-capture-autocomplete-input-change-event) is linked to yours, and it made me try the following that works with Firefox. (I didn't try it on other browsers)

```
$('#input1').bind('input',function(){
  if($(this).val().trim().length != 0){
    $('#input2').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because in FF, when an input is disabled it is really disabled (it doesn't receive mouse clicks).

Clicking on your disabled element doen't produces a blur event (focus lost) on input1, so the onchange doesn't gets fired.

You can workaround this easily with some classes and jQuery. For example:

```
<input class=disabled id=input2>
```

some css:

```
.disabled { background: #888; }
```

and then...

```
$(function(){
  // disable keypresses on "disabled" input
  $('.disabled').keypress(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    e.stopPropagation;
    return false;
  });
  // doesn't allow to focus
  $('.disabled').focus(function(e){
    $(this).blur();
  });
});
```

to activate the "disabled" element:

```
$('#input2').removeClass('disabled');
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SVtDj/11/

Answer (score 0):

See the answer of @Andy E in this post [Jquery event on a disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input), i think it is the best solution to resolve your problem.